# XSD : How to use ENTITY in XSD

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

XML

```
<copyright>&company; &department; &student_number; &developer;</copyright>
```

XSD

```
<xsd:element name="copyright" type="xsd:ENTITY">
 <xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element ref="&copyright" />
   <xsd:element ref="&department" />
   <xsd:element ref="&student_number" />
   <xsd:element ref="&developer" />
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="&copyright">
 .....  ENTITY description  ......
</xsd:element>
```

I try that.
But Don't work....

How to use ENTITY in XSD?? I'm looking for the google, XML Book, ETC.. But I couldn't find....

Comment: Could you describe what you actually want to achieve? It does not really become clear from your code samples.

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like you're trying to *declare* some entities in your schema - this is not possible, entities must be declared in a DTD, not a schema.

The purpose of the `xsd:ENTITY` type is to declare that a particular attribute refers to an *unparsed entity* which has been declared in the document's DTD:

```
<!DOCTYPE example [
  <!NOTATION png SYSTEM "PNG">
  <!ENTITY photoOfIan SYSTEM "ian-photo.png" NDATA png>
]>
<example>
  <person name="Ian Roberts" picture="photoOfIan" />
</example>
```

I don't think it's possible to say in an XML schema that a particular attribute value must be a reference to a normal *parsed* entity, since the schema validates the content that you get *after* `&xxxxx;` entity references have been expanded.

Answer (score 3):

1) Characters "&", "<", ">" are reserved and are forbidden to use names of elements and their values. You have to remove character "&" from the announcement of names.

2) You incorrectly declared type. You should use attribute "type" **OR** "Russian doll" declaration. Choose only one:

`<xsd:element name="copyright" type="xsd:ENTITY"/>`

or

```
<xsd:element name="copyright">
 <xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:sequence>
      ...element declaration...
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

3) I think you are doing is not what you need. The XSD scheme

`<xsd:element name="copyright">
     <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:element name="copyright" type="xsd:string" />
       <xsd:element name="department" type="xsd:string" />
       <xsd:element name="student_number" type="xsd:string" />
       <xsd:element name="developer" type="xsd:string" />
      </xsd:sequence>
     </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>`

translated in this document:

```
<copyright>
  <copyright>string</copyright>
  <department>string</department>
  <student_number>string</student_number>
  <developer>string</developer>
</copyright>
```

4) If you want to get a concatenated string, you need to define an element with a simple string type and on the application side to combine insert value. XML does not allow to do what you want.